# How to initialise multiple apps from firestore using aws ec2 engine?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, firebase, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-firestore

I am using same firestore database for multiple apps like iOS and android. And i have done backend for push notification using node js. Right now, I am trying to deploy backend in ec2 engine using AWS. While running server temporally in  in terminal, I used command node index.js and console output shows **Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail**.

here the screenshot of database [image]

here is the console output from terminal [image]

here is the code used in node js

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.cert({
projectId: '',
clientEmail: '',
privateKey: ''
}),
databaseURL: ''
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign the initialization to a variable and add a second argument of any string. This will let it know it is a secondary initialization. Take a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/).

```
var second = admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
        projectId: '',
        clientEmail: '',
        privateKey: ''
    }),
    databaseURL: ''
}, 'secondary');
```

Comment: Works absolutely perfectly

Comment: @eddyoc feel free to mark as correct for others to see if they stumble upon this!